# How to capture a line break as a browser event with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

Is it possible to capture non-forced line breaks (i.e. not hard coded with a `<br />` tag) as browser events, so paragraphs can be manipulated with `addEventListener()`, `createElement()`, etc. every time a line break happens?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Text layout is not exposed to the DOM that way.

Comment: Example? Well, actually I doubt one exist because everyone's monitor is different.

Comment: If you really want one, you might want to create hidden `div`s and check the height of said `div`s and append characters to them until their height changes. Like `sss` -> height = 12px, `sssss` -> height = 12, `sssssss` -> height = 24px, there is a non-forced line break.

Comment: Source code is not an event.  Can you give a more meaningful explanation of what you are trying to achieve and why?  Why are these line breaks so problematic to you?  If you want to manipulate individual paragraphs, why wouldn't you just put `<p>` tags around the content to give you an easy DOM node to work with?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to actually achieve? The direct answer to your question is that you cannot do that. However, if you would explain the goal, you might get helpful suggestions.

Comment: You might be looking for [`getClientRects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects). It's not an event of course.